# Git: can't remove a tar file from staging area

Tags: git

I created a git repository named "**repo_example**" on my Github account.

Then, I cloned another distant repository on my local machine and I removed the *.git* folder.

Then I created a new .git folder with

```
git init
```

then

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/myprofile/repo_example.git
```

then

```
git push -u origin main
```

But, I always get an error regarding a file that is too big:

> remote: error: Trace:
> c61a69d6ad7b1eb819b442df0c034bd5afac8629ca7a3408a981da20db2066ce
> remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information. remote:
> error: File datasets.tar is 1075.42 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file
> size limit of 100.00 MB remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
> You may want to try Git Large File Storage -
> https://git-lfs.github.com.

I checked if the file **datasets.tar** was present in my local repo, but it's not, I think I had deleted it a while ago.

I also tried:

```
git rm datasets.tar
```

and

```
git rm \*.tar
```

But I get:

> fatal: pathspec 'datasets.tar' did not match any files

I am really stuck here. Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: In particular, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602985/147356) on the duplicate question.

Comment: Indeed, git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f DVD-rip' HEAD worked